# Combinatorics - # of ways to choose people to 2 groups with condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a class there are 30 students, we need to choose 2 groups of 11 students so they can play against each other. Josh, one of the pupils has to be in one of the groups.

What I did is this:

We'll put Josh inside one of the groups, can calculate in how many ways we can choose 10 players for the first group and 11 for the second:

${29 \choose 10} \cdot {19 \choose 11} $

Multiply by 2 (for the possibility that Josh is in the second group):

${29 \choose 10} \cdot {19 \choose 11} \cdot 2$

I'm not quite sure about my solution, can anyone verify it or tell me how to solve this right?

Thanks.

Comment: We are choosing where Josh goes. There is no possibility that he could be in the other group. Other than that, it seems good to me!

Comment: Josh will always be in the group we put Josh in.  Everything else is okay,

Comment: @GrahamKemp, so is my proof OK?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We put Josh in one group, and that's the group he will be in.   He won't ever be in the group he's not in.

All that remains is to select the $10$ other players for the group Josh is in and the $11$ players for the group Josh is not in.

$$\dbinom{29}{10}\dbinom{19}{11}$$

That is all.   There isn't anything else.